# javascript conversion string to UTC date

Tags: javascript, utc

I'm converting string to timestamp by using

```
 var  timestamp = new Date(month+"/"+day+"/"+year).getTime()/ 1000;
```

My question is how to set it as UTC timezone before converting to timestamp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Date.UTC()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp) method instead of `.getTime()`.

```
var timestamp = Date.UTC(year,month,day) / 1000;
```

(Note: the month is expected to be from 0-11, not 1-12.)